# How to load more than one profile at a time in flutter?

Tags: android, ios, firebase, flutter

I am building one app in that I have to display multiple profiles one by one. When user sees the first profile and click on connect or decline button then he/she will see the second profile and so on. But in my app it loads every time when another user come, instead, I want to do such that when a user sees first profile at that time in the background I can load other 3 users Image and data, so I don't have to show loading spinner every time, so is there any way to do that in flutter?

```
 fetchUserImage(int currentIndex) async {
            setState(() {
              isLoading = true;
            }); 
    
    await FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection("users")
            .where("username", isEqualTo: username)
            .get()
            .then((val) {
          userId = val.docs[0]['uid'];
          print("This is userId");
          print(userId);
        });
    
        await FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection("imageCount")
            .doc(userId)
            .get()
            .then((val) {
          imgCnt = val['cnt'];
          print('This is image count');
          print(imgCnt);
        });
    
        await FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection("imageURLs")
            .doc(userId)
            .get()
            .then((val) {
          for (int i = 0; i < imgCnt; i++) {
            print('This is ' + i.toString() + " url");
            imgUrls![i] = val[i.toString()];
            print(imgUrls![i]);
          }
        });
 setState(() {
      isLoading = false;
    });
  }
```

Here is the code to fetch one user image.

Comment: Please share what you have done in terms of code

Comment: @Muhtar Till now, I have fetched only one user profile image and I don't have an idea how to do it while the user sees the first profile meanwhile I have to load the other 3 user's data.